# .NET - Collections and inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, collections, observablecollection

I have three classes with common parent. Let's say parent is Animal and children are Dog,Cat and Parrot.

And I have one observable collection which contains collection of animals user is working with. Collection contains all animals of same type  - user is either working only with all dogs or all cats or all parrots.

So I declared `ObservableCollection<Animal>` animals and depending on user choices I want to change contents of property animals to `ObservableCollection<Dog>` or `ObservableCollection<Cat>` or `ObservableCollection<PArrot>`. So it doesn't matter if user currently works with dogs or cats but he can choose all actions animals have in common.

But it doesn't work. It seems that I can't assign `ObservableCollection<Cat>` to Property of type `ObservableCollection<animal>`. I would think it should work, because animal is supertype of cat, so I can assign cat to animal variable as usual.

Why can't I do this and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason it doesn't work: if it **did** work, you could have the nonsense scenario:

```
ObservableCollection<Animal> animals = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();
animals.Add(new Cat()); // cat is an animal, after all
```

Another reason is that it is simply not the case that `ObservableCollection<Dog>` *inherits* `ObservableCollection<Animal>` - they are just different (parallel) closed generic types of `ObservableCollection<>`.

What *is* permitted is that some interfaces with "out only" APIs (such as `IEnumerable<T>`) can be *covariant*, so if all you need is to *iterate* them, you can have:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();
```

(presumably *adding* the dogs somewhere else)

Another approach would be to use a non-generic API:

```
IList animals = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ObservableCollection`, you'll have to type these collections as `IEnumerable<T>`, since `ObservableCollection` does not support type covariance.  No collection that allows you to **add** elements will ever support this type of inheritance.  To see why, consider this hypothetical code (which does **not** compile)

```
List<object> myObjects = new List<string>();
```

You'd think this would be ok, but then look what would happen if you then wrote the following:

```
myObjects.Add(new Dog());
```

`myObjects` is declared as a List of objects, so the above code would compile, but at runtime things would blow up since, under the covers, `myObjects` is instantiated to only hold strings.

Comment: no regular collection types support covariance; a: it is impossible to be a collection type with an Add and a mechanism to get values out *and* support variance, and b: only interfaces and delegates support 4.0-style variance, meaning: `IEnumerable<out T>`, but not the class itself.

Comment: I am using C# 4.0. I am binding to this collection, so i need to use ObservableCollection. Is that possible?

Comment: @Marc - I know all that - can you tell me what part of my answer implied otherwise so I can be more clear?

Comment: That'll be the bit before your ninja edit, where it was less explicit ;p

Comment: @Marc - I guess it's lost to history :)  -- thanks for calling me on it though

Answer (score 0):

Make it an interface, and use **[co-variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)**

```
interface ObservableCollection <out T>
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont over-complicate it with covariance if you dont need to. 
You should create `ObservableCollection<Animal>` irregardless of whether you are filling it with Cats, Dogs or Parrots since you don't use any subclassed functionality.

You have not mentioned why you use ObervableCollection, but if you don't observe it and do not care about being notified of changes to the list you might as well transform it.